# Парсинг txt средствами PHP

Tags: php, парсер

Как можно реализовать парсинг txt файла такого формата:

```
text ===============<<{{((093214432))}}>>============== text ===============<<{{((04324234))}}>>============== text
```

С целью получения данных в скобках - `( 093214432 , 04324234 )`. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `preg_match('/(\(\d+\))/',$text,$match)`

Comment: @Mike а если данне не числовые?  что тогда? регулярка зло для парсинга чего либо особенно много памяти квадратичныя сложность алгоритма и т.д.

Comment: от автора вопроса требуеться кусок файлп с переносом строкеть и другими символами

Comment: @Naumov Где вы видите в этой регулярке квадратичную сложность ? Бактракинг исключен т.к. ищем фиксированный набор. если нужны не цифры, то сверхжадно захватывать все НЕ скобки (`[^)]++`). На такой регулярке построится простейший однопроходный КА, который отработает за линейное время практически не уступая такому же КА реализованному специально под задачу.

Comment: @Mike ok вдруг в файле окажеться {{()(35)}} эх незадача опять не та регулярка. Да и вот незадача вы захватываете лишние (). Одна регулярка а вам придеться уже 3й раз ее править. Тут и есть истина допиливаем регулярку -> она становиться сложнее и т.д. вам надо почитать о правильной скобочной последовательности. Ибо с регулярками не достигнуть успеха. Вам надо проверять верно ли раставлены скобки и символы в файле а потом производить парсинг. Да и текст в примере не случайный.

Comment: @Naumov Если бы я считал, что эта регулярка может быть точным ответом на вопрос, я бы и написал ее ответом. Как комментарий она написана только с целью возможно натолкнуть автора на какое нибудь самостоятельное решение проблемы. И на вопрос она отвечает в той степени в какой текст вопроса описывает реальную задачу. т.е. очень размытое. В половине случаев под парсингом ТС понимают тупо выдрать кусок текста без глубокого анализа и регулярки для таких целей отлично подходят. P.S. и из вашего примера она отлично получит 35

Comment: Согласен с @Mike. Комментарий не отвечает исчерпывающе на вопрос, поскольку не выдает в качестве результата строку ( х, у ), но автор вопроса легко решит проблему сам с помощью регулярок.